# How to correctly implement a inline if statement in a html tag?

Tags: php, html

I want to have the checkbox seleted if the productNeedsAudit from the Json value is True.  But I new to php and I am also stuck implementing the logic with an echo statement.  I am trying the following:

```
echo "<tr><td><div class='control-group controls'>
          <label for='productNeedsAudit'>
                    <input name='productNeedsAudit' type='checkbox'id='productNeedsAudit'  value='True'" . $soJson->{'productNeedsAudit'} == 'True' ? 'checked' : '' . ">
                        Needs Audit
               </label> 
      </div></td></tr>";
```

In the results, the check box isn't selected.  Instead,  I am getting the following in the web browser.

```
> Needs Audit
```

Here's the HTML

```
<table>
   <tr>
      <td>
         <select style='width: 100%;' id='productType' name='productType'>
            <option value='TEST: TEST</option>
         </select>
      </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>
         <div class='control-group controls'>
            <label for='productDescription'>Description: </label>
            <input type='text' name='productDescription' value='*.1stdibs.com, *.1stdibs.us.com' />
         </div>
      </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>
         <div class='control-group controls'>
            <label for='productPriceBookDescription'>Price Book Description: </label>
            <input type='text' id='priceBookDesc' name='productPriceBookDescription' style='width:100%' value='' />
         </div>
      </td>
   </tr>
   />
   Needs Audit
   </label> 
   </div></td></tr>
   <tr>
      <td>
         <div class='control-group controls'>
            <label for='productServiceOrderNumber'>Service Order: </label>
            <select  id='productServiceOrderNumber' name='productServiceOrderNumber'>
               <option value='992769:53:14' selected='selected'>992769:53:14</option>
            </select>
         </div>
      </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>
         <input id='subcustomers' name='subcustomers'>
         </input>
         <input id='subproducts' name='subproducts'>
         </input>
      </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>
         <input id='tags' name='tags'>
         </input>
      </td>
   </tr>
   </td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Can you give the output `html` source code result please?

Comment: Chris, your syntax worked.  Can you add it as an answer and explain why it works?

Comment: Write up written. Post if you have questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Group the ternary operator.

```
echo "<tr><td><div class='control-group controls'>
          <label for='productNeedsAudit'>
                    <input name='productNeedsAudit' type='checkbox'id='productNeedsAudit'  value='True'" . ($soJson->{'productNeedsAudit'} == 'True' ? ' checked' : '') . ">
                        Needs Audit
               </label> 
      </div></td></tr>";
```

Longer write up on ternary operator. http://davidwalsh.name/php-shorthand-if-else-ternary-operators

Functional example:

```
<?php
$a = "False";
echo "<tr><td><div class='control-group controls'>
          <label for='productNeedsAudit'>
                    <input name='productNeedsAudit' type='checkbox'id='productNeedsAudit'  value='True'" . ($a == 'True' ? ' checked' : '') . ">
                        Needs Audit
               </label> 
      </div></td></tr>";
```

Output:

```
<tr><td><div class='control-group controls'>
          <label for='productNeedsAudit'>
                    <input name='productNeedsAudit' type='checkbox'id='productNeedsAudit'  value='True'>
                        Needs Audit
               </label> 
      </div></td></tr>
```

As true:

```
<tr><td><div class='control-group controls'>
          <label for='productNeedsAudit'>
                    <input name='productNeedsAudit' type='checkbox'id='productNeedsAudit'  value='True'checked>
                        Needs Audit
               </label> 
      </div></td></tr>
```

Note I added a space in the `checked` attribute. I think some browsers also prefer that to be `checked="checked"`.

When your expression isn't grouped the PHP is checking does " `<tr><td><div class='control-group controls'><label for='productNeedsAudit'><input name='productNeedsAudit' type='checkbox'id='productNeedsAudit' value='True'` +  what ever `$soJson->{'productNeedsAudit'}` is" equal `True`. Since it doesn't it goes to the second part of the ternary operator and outputs:

```
'' . ">
                        Needs Audit
               </label> 
      </div></td></tr>"
```